How to a reference my application dbcontext while building a singleton class for DI?
In my .NET 7 Program.cs class I am attempting to use the dbcontext defined earlier as part of the constructor for my singleton class:
 builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), o => o.EnableRetryOnFailure()));

 builder.Services.AddSingleton<IApplicationSettings, ApplicationSettings>(a =>
 {
     var dbContext = a.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
     return new ApplicationSettings(new List<string> { "workers.maintenance", "shared" }, dbContext);
 });


ApplicationSettings constructor:
public ApplicationSettings(IEnumerable<string> names, ApplicationDbContext dbContext)

When this runs I get the following error:

cannot resolve scoped service from root provider

for this line:
var dbContext = a.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();


The default register lifetime of AddDbContext(...) is "scoped". You cannot use "scoped" service inside a "Singleton" configuration. The life time must be >= the configured service.
So you could set the DbContext as ServiceLifetime.Singleton
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>  options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),o => o.EnableRetryOnFailure())
, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

Or if you don't want to change the dbcontext lifescope you could create another "ApplicationDbContext2" for register.

That's a serious bug. A DbContext is scoped because it's a Unit-of-Work. To "rollback" you dispose it. If you keep it around you risk persisting changes you thought were discarded an hour ago
